# Evaluating command inside JQ pipeline

Tags: jq

I'm struggling evaluating a command inside a jq pipeline. Example will make it easier. Let's imagine I've got this simple json

```
{
    "model": [{
            "id": "an-id",
            "path": [
                "mypath1.txt"
            ],
            "model": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "an-id2",
            "path": [
                "mypath1.txt"
            ],
            "model": "foo2"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to convert into this

```
 {
    "model": [{
            "id": "an-id",
            "path": [
                "mypath1.txt"
            ],
            "model": "foo",
            "alternative_model": "I am a computed value out of <foo>"
        },
        {
            "id": "an-id2",
            "path": [
                "mypath1.txt"
            ],
            "model": "foo2",
            "alternative_model": "I am a computed value out of <foo2>"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to do something like this that allows me to delegate computing alternative model to a different bash script.

```
  myNewJson=$(cat mappings.json | jq '[.model[]| {
        id: .id,
        path: .path
        model: .model
        alternative_model: //TODO}' ---> here I'd like to do something like "eval ./myscript $model" 
])
```

Thanks!

Comment: You cannot shell out from jq ([yet?](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/147)). Therefore, you'd need one script to extract a list of items or references to loop over, realize that loop in the shell producing a list of results, and then read that list back into your JSON for merging. jq can help you with the first and the last step, but not with the middle one, which is why there is no jq-only single-script solution to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume `myscript` contains following line :

```
echo "I am a computed value out of <$1>"
```

As `jq` does not allow to evaluate shell commands, you need something like :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
input=mappings.json

alternative-models(){
    local result='{}' sres
    for id in $(jq -r '.model[].id' $input); do
        model="$(jq -r --arg id "$id" '.model[]|select(.id==$id).model' $input)"
        amodel="$(./myscript $model)"
        result="$(jq --arg id $id --arg amodel "$amodel" '. + { $id: $amodel }' <<< "$result")"
    done
    echo "$result"
}

jq --argjson amodels "$(alternative-models)" '.model|map({
        id, path, model, "alternative_model": $amodels[.id] }
)' $input
```

Your mappings.json is not valid json because of a comma on the `model` line.